# What is the correct way of calculating the average percentage in this scenario?

Tags: percentages

Assume that there two people working in a call centre: PersonA and PersonB.

They are both waiting for calls in separate locations.

I want to calculate the average amount of time spent waiting overall.

The scenario is this:

> PersonA spends 50 minutes out of 100 (50.00%) waiting for calls to
>   come in (the other 50 minutes were spent on calls).
>
> PersonB spends 900 minutes out of 1000 (90.00%) waiting for calls to
>   come in (the other 100 minutes were spent on calls).

**My question is this: what is the correct way to calculate the average waiting time across both people?**

**Should I take an average of their respective time-spent-waiting percentages or should I take into account their collective total available time when working this out?**

I have tried taking the average of PersonA's and PersonB's time-spent-waiting percentages, which seems plausible:

`AVERAGE(0.5, 0.9) = 0.7 (70.00%)`

I understand this to mean that, on average, the time spent waiting was 70.00% across both people.

But then, taking into consideration PersonA and PersonB's **total available times** when calculating this also seems plausible:

`950 minutes (waiting) / 1100 minutes (total available time) = 86.36%`

Which I understand to mean that, out of 1100 minutes of total availability, the average amount of time spent waiting across both people was 86.36%.

**What is the difference, and which is the correct way to calculate this in this scenario (and why)?**

Comment: This isn't really a math question.  Both averages make sense, but they measure different things.  If you are interested in getting a base line on employee efficiency, you should average the two averages.  If, on the other hand, you want to get a baseline on how much wait time is involved in a call, you should look at each call.

Comment: That makes sense. Also, I wondered if this belonged here or on a Stats SE site, so opted for here.

Comment: Oh, I think this is a fine place for it.

Comment: Great. So assuming that each employee is available for a different amount of time, then is the first calculation (average of averages) the correct one to use?  If so, why?

Comment: As I say, "correct" depends on what you are trying to measure.  If I have a lot of students taking Calculus, with a lot of tests, I can compare the averages of two students, even if they have taken different numbers of tests (or different tests).  Makes perfect sense.  Or, if I am trying to assess how difficult my tests are, I can look at the scores on each test and average them.  This also makes perfect sense, though the two averages are different.

Comment: To stress:  any kind of summary statistic has flaws.  If my Calculus students average $75$ while yours average $80$ then maybe you have better students or maybe my tests are harder, no way to tell.  With your phone calls, it's natural to assume homogeneity amongst the calls but maybe that's not realistic.  Maybe we should be controlling for the time at which the calls occur, or the location of the caller.  Who knows?   Data is messy.

Comment: Yes, of course. What I am trying to measure is the percentage of time my employees spent waiting for calls on average, regardless of how long they were available for. In that case, might the first calculation be the (for lack of a better word) "correct" one to use?  Or is there a better way to do it?  In short, without delving too deep into the data, what might be the best way to calculate the average waiting time of, say, 500 employees, each with varying availability?  Would the simplest solution be to take an average of their individual average waiting times?

Comment: If you want to take the employee out of the picture then you should average over each call, Or in this case, "call-minutes".  so your second method would be better.

Comment: Here you have $150$ call minutes and $950$ wait minutes so I'd say you have $6.\overline 3$ wait minutes per call minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83993/discussion-between-snookerfan-and-lulu).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for that right now.

Comment: Not to worry.  Would you please explain how you reached that solution? I'm having trouble accepting one solution over the other here because the other answer to this question (from user247327) makes a case that seems totally plausible to me. I guess what I'm having trouble with is how to determine which solution is best-suited for my scenario (with no disrespect to either of you, of course).

Comment: My measure is an efficiency measure...in order to get $X$ amount of call time in, how much wasted time will there be?  The other average asks "out of a given time period, how much time will be wasted".  If the calls were truly homogeneous, you'd expect these answers to be similar.  They are not, in this case, because your second employee obviously spends a lot less time on individual calls.

Comment: To clarify the difference, my measure would be better if you value client interaction (so long calls are better than short calls).  The other method is better if what you value is the number of calls.

Comment: Client interaction is the priority here, but I am more interested in the volume of calls rather than their duration because I quite literally have several thousand employees so there is often always enough supply to meet demand in that respect. However, it is those times when supply doesn't meet demand that I want to focus on.  I want to find out the average percentage of time (regardless of what that is) that my employees spend waiting for calls to come in so that I can take the appropriate action in those respective locations (i.e. relocating some employee, etc.).

Comment: Your solution makes sense, but I guess that I am looking at the inverse of it.  As such, would one of the two examples that I have given be more suitable than the other or would it be something else?

Comment: If you care more about call volume rather than call-time then I agree with the other method...fix a block of time.

Comment: Yes, I care more about call volume than duration. So an average of averages (`AVERAGE(0.5, 0.9) = 0.7 (70.00%)`) is better-suited here?

Comment: Again, though, I am making some assumptions here.  I am looking at the great disparity between the two employees and I am assuming that it is explained by saying that the second spends a lot less time per call.  Of course, other explanations are possible.  But why make assumptions?  Presumably you have all the data...if you are interested in call volume, measure that.  How many calls per hour do employees handle?  Sounds like that would be a better measure for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to average over the **same time interval**.  Take the time interval to be 1000 minutes.  A spends 50% of that, 500 minutes, waiting.  B spends 90% of that, 900 minutes, waiting. They spend a total of 500+ 900= 1400 minutes waiting out of a total of 2000 minutes.  Together they average 1400/2000= .7 or 70% of their time waiting.  That is, of course, exactly the same as (50+ 90)/2= 70 since the "base" in both cases is the same- time. Your second calculation is wrong because you used different time intervals.

Comment: So how do I get the average if the time intervals are different, like in the example?  Or is this the correct way to do it (by scaling both PersonA and PersonB's available times to match)?